# Problemas con excedente en HTML

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo un problema con HTML, por ejemplo, tengo un contenedor, dentro del contenedor tengo varios elementos y entre ellos hay un elemento `<p>`, el problema consta en que llega un punto en el cual el texto dentro del `<p>` es demasiado y provoca que el texto o el `<p>` se salga del contenedor.

Esto se debe a que establecí un `width` del `20%`, y es necesario que tenga esa anchura, mi pregunta es ¿Como hago para que en ves de que siga el texto de largo, cuando este al limite del contenedor haga un salto de linea?

Este seria mi archivo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <h2>Tituloooooooooooo</h2>
            <p class="price">500$</p>
            <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h2>Tituloooooooooooo</h2>
            <p class="price">500$</p>
            <p class="">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este mi archivo CSS:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.column {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 5px 12px 25px 12px;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Este seria la imagen de como se visualiza el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]De antemano gracias por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para que la palabra sea *"cortada"* y genere un salto de línea podrías usar:

### Opción 1:

[`overflow-wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-wrap)

> La propiedad CSS de `overflow-wrap` se aplica a los elementos en línea, estableciendo si el navegador debe insertar saltos de línea dentro de una cadena que de otra manera sería irrompible para evitar que el texto se desborde en su cuadro de línea.

Al establecer `overlfow-word` igual a `break-word` obtenemos que:

> Las palabras normalmente irrompibles pueden romperse en puntos arbitrarios si no hay puntos de corte aceptables en la línea, pero las oportunidades de ajuste suave introducidas por la palabra salto no se consideran al calcular los tamaños intrínsecos de contenido mínimo.

#### Demo

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow-wrap: break-word
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 12px 25px 12px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Tituloooooooooooo</h2>
    <p class="price">500$</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Tituloooooooooooo</h2>
    <p class="price">500$</p>
    <p class="">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Opción 2:

[word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)

> La propiedad de CSS `word-break` establece si los saltos de línea aparecen donde el texto desbordaría su cuadro de contenido.

Al establecer `word-break` igual a `break-all` obtenemos que:

> Para evitar el desbordamiento, se deben insertar saltos de palabras entre dos caracteres (excluyendo el texto chino / japonés / coreano).

#### Demo

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-flow: wrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-all
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px 12px 25px 12px;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Tituloooooooooooo</h2>
    <p class="price">500$</p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>Tituloooooooooooo</h2>
    <p class="price">500$</p>
    <p class="">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</div>
```